# String to int cast in php

Tags: php, string, validation, casting

Ok I just stumbled upon a strange behavior in PHP while trying to
validate if the user input is an integer.

When I try to cast a string `12345A` to int e.g

```
$int_var = (int)'12345A';
```

I get 12345.

Why isn't PHP throwing an exception, but silently omits the 'A'?

Comment: Because that's what it's designed to do?

Comment: So should I go with a loop through the string and check if the character is a number?

Comment: the latter is better when you have a 32 bit system and you want a huge int that is higher than PHP_MAX_INT.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Depends on what you're after. What's your usecase? Are you wanting it to fail if it contains non-numeric characters? Perhaps `is_numeric`, `is_int` or `ctype_digit`.

Comment: I am validating if the user input is an integer.

Comment: read type juggling : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP tries to convert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) the initial part of the string to integer type:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

The type casting feature is not supposed to throw exceptions, or fail in any other way, if the variable being cast is scalar. It will trigger a notice, if the variable is an object, but the conversion will be performed, nevertheless.

If you want to check, if `$t` variable contains a numeric value, use `is_numeric`:

```
if (is_numeric($t)) {
  // ...
}
```

Don't use `is_int`, since if `$t` is a string like `'1234'` (which is usually the case), then `is_int` will return `false`, because the type is `string`, but not `int`.

Also, consider `trim`ming `$t` before the checks:

```
$t = trim($t);
```

since the user may submit something like `" 123"`. But the application usually should not fail just because of the leading space.

Answer (score 3):

When you do a cast like this, PHP will do its best to convert to a number, including stripping off non-digit characters.

If you want to be sure it's an int, you can use `is_int()`, as in:

```
$t = '12345A';
if (!is_int($t)) throw new Exception('Not an integer: ' . $t);
```

Comment: This will fail because $t is not an integer, it's a string. See the accepted answer.